# Why is my mesh "drooping" when I apply automatic weighting

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones, vertex-weights

I'm working on a mesh of a person for school, trying to rig him and get him ready to animate, but when I apply automatic weights, my mesh begins to droop in the arms, torso, and eye ball. Not sure why? Everyone else's works very well in the tutorials. Any idea why mine is drooping and how to fix it? Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hey, Moon boots! I just uploaded the file for you! :)

Comment: Typically, current pose is not the rest pose: in pose mode select all and apply pose as rest pose (use Ctrl+A).

Comment: You'll need to give some corrections in Weight Paint mode, but before that, maybe join all the objects (it will make things easier to work imho), put the Armature modifier above the other ones, also your IK Pole Angle is not good for both the 2 arms...

Comment: I posted the result when I tried to join him. Pretty creepy right? Any idea what I did wrong? I selected all of him and clicked join

Comment: yes you need to apply some modifiers before, like Mirror, Bevel, Solidify, but not Subdivision Surface modifiers, otherwise the object that is joined will loose its modifiers and it will take the ones of the object it is joined to

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! My rig is working so much better now! The only thing is, when I pose my character's arm, his hair and "ear communicator" and sometimes the visor of his hat move with the arm. Also when he kicks, his shoe/foot detatches from the mesh. I joined him altogether in one object. Any idea why that is acting like that?